# MVC: I am using MultiSelectList and when I select two values it just sends one value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, listbox

I using MVC-Viewmodel in my project, my problem is that even if i CTRL-click two values in my listbox It only grabs one value. I want users to be able to select two values but I dont know why it doesnt happen any tips is appreciated!

Here is my GET n POST action inside my controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{          
    CreateViewModel model = new CreateViewModel();
    List<CoreValue> corevalues = Arep.getallC();
    model.CoreValuess = new MultiSelectList(corevalues, "CID", "Cname");  
    return View(model);

} 

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Question q = new Question();

      var CoreValueID = int.Parse(model.Cname);
      var getallC = Arep.getbycid(CoreValueID);

      q.CoreValue.Add(getallC);
      q.QuestionText = model.QuestionText;
      Arep.addquestion(q);
      Arep.save();


        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(model);
```

This is inside my CreateViewModel:

```
public MultiSelectList CoreValues { get; set; }
```

And this is inside my View:

```
 @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.Cname,Model.Corevaluess)
```

What seem to be the problem?

Thanks in Advance!

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

Spelling errors aside, I believe the following is why this is failing:

In your ListBoxFor method, you are using model.Cname. By this, I believe you mean "choose the cName of selected CoreValues". However (and I'm guessing because I can't see your model), the Cname property on the CreateViewModel is of type string. Because of this, you are only ever going to have one value at a time. You need a property that is of type IEnumerable in order to hold multiple selections.

Update your model to the following:

```
public class CreateViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<string> SelectedValues { get; set; } 
    public IEnumerable<CoreValue> CoreValues { get; set; }
}
```

SelectedValues will be used to contain the selected values on the post. We can also add items to it to signify what should be automatically selected when the view is created.

In your controller do the following:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{          
    CreateViewModel model = new CreateViewModel();
    model.CoreValues = Arep.getallC();
    return View(model);
}
```

Lastly, update the view:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedValues, new MultiSelectList(Model.CoreValues, "CID", "Cname"))
```

Now, whenever you post, you should be able to see the values that a user selected.

EDIT: I'm not completely sure what some of your methods do so I'm taking a guess.

The POST method for Create:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        foreach(var CoreValueID in model.SelectedValues)
        {
            Question q = new Question();

            var getallC = Arep.getbycid(CoreValueID);

            q.CoreValue.Add(getallC);
            q.QuestionText = model.QuestionText;
            Arep.addquestion(q);
        }

        Arep.save();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: How should the Actionresult create POST look like?

Answer (score 0):

> you would need to pass selectedvalues as below

```
List<CoreValue> selectedvalues = Null;
model.CoreValuess = new MultiSelectList(corevalues, "CID", "Cname",selectedvalues);  
return View(model);
```

Refer [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470158.aspx) and [this helpful Article](http://blog.garypretty.co.uk/index.php/2010/02/26/multi-select-list-box-in-asp-net-mvc/)

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, the ASP.Net Mvc wants to have a list of string, but the same thing can be achieved by using the classic ASP style

```
Request.Form["CoreValues"]
```

this will provide as comma separated values.